# unable to type in password at login screen after restart?

Tags: 13.10, login, login-screen

I am locked out of my laptop after restarting it. When I am in the login screen, I have 3 options:

1. me / registered user
2. guest session
3. remote login

When I click on the password field/text box that says `log in`, or press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it disappears. I can only press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and i am taken back to the 3 options, so I tried to just start typing the password, but nothing happens.

- What can the problem be? Ubuntu did install some updates and I installed `GIMP` and `libimobiledevice`.

I tried to look for previous questions/answers, but nothing seem to match my problem. Can anyone help? I am a novice here and I don't want to give up or start from scratch. I have done so much on it already.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using GUI press Ctrl+Alt+F1 (if F1 key does not work try using other F# keys) at the log-in screen. This should bring CLi. You can always get back to GUI log-in page by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7

You will be prompted for username and password. Try logging this way. After you logged in to start your GUI type:

```
startx -- :1
```

Your GUI will load up. At that point you can use your command prompt or other GUI tools to troubleshoot the issue.

It is possible that reading this links my help in troubleshooting your issue: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) or [login loop ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314259/login-loop-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Thank you I can login this way: Ctrl+Alt+F4 but then I am lost again. After typing startx -- :1 I get the terminal and no GUI. no idea what I am doing

Comment: pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7 does niothing

Comment: when you login though the CLi try the following commands:[code]sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop[code]

Comment: sorry for some reason i cannot properly format the answer, ghhh

Comment: People had similar problems. this issue can be fixed via recovery mode by fixing broken packages or by reinstall.Please take a look at this link the directions for both ways are there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125798/cannot-pass-the-login-screen-after-upgrade-to-12-04-from-11-10[link]

Comment: thank you all! In the end, did a ubuntu reinstall and reinstall some software afterbut saved my files. a lot of work!! I will bear these answers in mind if it happens again.