# Can't log on after upgrading to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, login-screen

When I get to the login screen after upgrading I can't click the typing box to enter my password the only thing I can click is the shutdown and volume controls in the top bar. This happens every time I try.

I can't do a fresh install of 17.04 as I get an error when doing so. I was trying to upgrade from 16.04 instead when this happened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437850/unable-to-type-in-password-at-login-screen-after-restart) question

Comment: re: "I can't do a fresh install of 17.04 as I get an error when doing so."... ok... what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way! If anyone else has this issue you can click the icon of a man in a circle (no idea what it's actually called) to give the accessibility options. Select "Onscreen Keyboard" and use that to type in your log in and press enter on the onscreen keyboard. Clicking on the box doesn't show that you are in the typing field but you are so that should work. For some reason the physical keyboard won't work. That will get you in. Once you are in you need to reinstall xorg. Follow the steps here
[Laptop keyboard stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688445/laptop-keyboard-stopped-working)
Then restart and it should be up and running!